# "After you" when you go first to push the door

Tags: word-usage

Do you natives say "After you" even when you go first to open the door at the push-type door?

You have to go out from the room first when the door is the type of door which open toward outside.  Even in that case, if you hold the door for other people, do you say "After you"?

(I think it is natural to say "After you" when you pull and open the door to have other people go outside of the room first, but I wonder if I can say it even when I go out from the room first to open the door.)

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Comment: I would normally say "after you" if I pull open a door and want to ask the person behind to go before me. I would not say "after you" if I push open the door and just hold it open. If I absolutely felt like saying something, I might say, "Go ahead, please". However, normally a nod and smile are sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you're holding a door, whether you're letting someone in or out, it is considered appropriate to say **after you**. This is because you aren't necessarily saying you're going to literally follow after them, but rather you are saying that you will do the activity of entering or exiting after they have first entered or exited. That being said, you could also say **you first** or **go ahead**, and it would have the same meaning.

Comment: Please let me confirm.   Let's say that you are moving from the room A to room B directly connected to room A. You opened the door by pushing.  So you enter the room B first.  Even in that case, "After you" is appropriate. Right?

Comment: Nope, if you are just entering the room, and you hold the door for them as you enter, don't say anything usually. They will say "thank you" if they have manners, and you will say "you're welcome" and that's all.